# How to get with js ::placeholder color in browser Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, webkit

I tried to run this in the devtools console:

`window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('input'), '::-webkit-input-placeholder').getPropertyValue('color')`

`window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('input'), '::placeholder').getPropertyValue('color')`

on page: https://fianitnz.github.io/tests/ajenti2_login_page.html

In firefox, the second option works.

Comment: Not implemented, see https://crbug.com/922869.

Comment: Thank you @wOxxOm . I didn't find it.

Comment: If enable devtool option "Show user agent shadow DOM", in "elements" appears `<div pseudo="-webkit-input-placeholder" id="placeholder" style="display: block !important;">Username</div><div></div>` containing the desired style. Is there any other way to get this information out?